# Python: run a function at set interval while program runs

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns

I have a program that will be running 24/7 (assuming no server crashes). The program waits for users of a chat channel to issue commands, then it does several things based on the command issued and user permissions. This program will use and update data from Tuesday 10AM till next Tuesday 9AM, at which point, at 9AM, it will need to wipe the data and start over for the next week cycle.

I'm having trouble finding a way to implement the weekly reset though. I could restart the program every week, but was wondering if there is a way to run a background process that executes a function at a set interval (one week in this case). I was thinking of using a thread to keep track of time, and when a week has passed, have the thread execute the data wipe function. But wouldn't this be an unnecessarily expensive operation? Having a thread running at all times keeping track of passing time seems like a brute force solution.

I would greatly appreciate some pointers on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Since your program is already on for 24/7 couldn't you add a clean function in that one? Similar to how it is waiting for users to input commands, check if that time has passed and clear the data before executing the users command?

Comment: @Thymen So basically, before any command is actually executed, check if the week has passed and wipe the data before the command executes? So if the last command issued was on Monday 6AM, and a user issues a command on Monday 11AM, then the data is wiped and the command is executed... So while the data isn't precisely cleaned at 9AM on Monday, it doesn't matter because the very next command after 9AM on Monday would guarantee a clean slate for the coming week. I like that - and I was going to perpetually run a thread in the background...

Comment: Yeah, since the program was already up and running and interfacing with the data folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

next_wipe = get_next_wipe_datetime()  # typically Tue. 9am
...
cmd = read_chat_channel()   

if datetime.now() > next_wipe:
    next_wipe = get_next_wipe_datetime()
    do_wipe()

process(cmd)
```